# Android custom dialog button styles not applied

Tags: java, android, dialog

I wish to create a simple dialog for the user with 2 buttons as follows:

**Dialog Layout (dialog_layout.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_select_choice_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Choice"
        android:theme="@style/secondary_button_normal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_select_choice_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Choice"
        android:theme="@style/secondary_button_normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**secondary_button_normal:**

```
<style name="secondary_button_normal" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_secondary_normal_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_secondary_normal_text</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_textSize</item>
        <item name="android:padding">@dimen/button_padding</item>
</style>
```

**Activity's onCreate:**

```
final Dialog selection = new Dialog(this);
        selection.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
        Button selectFirstChoice = (Button)selection.findViewById(R.id.btn_select_choice_1);
        Button selectSecondChoice = (Button)selection.findViewById(R.id.btn_select_choice_2);
        selectFirstChoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                selection.dismiss();
            }
        });
        selectSecondChoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                selection.dismiss();
            }
        });
        selection.setTitle("Some Title");
        selection.setCancelable(false);
        selection.show();
```

The preview is alright:

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAAt5.png)

It works well on Nougat, but when I run it on Lollipop (5.0 and 5.1.1), the buttons are without styling, although the same button styling worked on activity buttons on Lollipop:

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6cKB.png)

I wonder what could be going wrong, I also tried moving the Dialog into a DialogFragment but I faced the same behavior.

Comment: Have you tried to put your style in folder res/values-v21/styles.xml. also ?

Comment: @Mohamed I tried but with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following solution:

In my Styles.xml, I added:

```
<style name="dialog_button" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_secondary_normal_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_secondary_normal_text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_textSize</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/button_padding</item>
</style>
```

And in my custom dialog layout, I used that style as a theme for my buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_select_student"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/student"
    android:theme="@style/dialog_button" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_select_tutor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/tutor"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/dialog_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```